# Strange behaviour of STM32 ADC with external trigger

Tags: timer, arm, stm32, adc, isr

I'm on STM32L476. I have setup my ADC to be triggered by TIM15. There is only one channel, single conversion mode. On ADC side, to enable interrupts I clear the ADC ISR register and then set ADC_IER, before starting the conversion.

If I enable in AED IER both EOSIE and EOCIE, everything works fine ie. I get the following sequence of IRQs:

- timer IRQ
- ADC EOC IRQ
- ADC EOS IRQ

However if I only enable EOSIE in ADC IER ( nothing else is changed ) I am losing on ADC IRQ out of 2 timer IRQ:

- timer IRQ #1
- timer IRQ #2 (corresponding to the following timer update)
- ADC EOS IRQ

Do you know where it comes from ? Is it explained by a bad setting of the ADC ?

Comment: No code no help

Comment: Well there are several functions involved, in timer and in ADC modules and as I pointed out the only thing that changed between both cases is the bit EOCIE that is enabled or not. Do you still need the code ?

Comment: are you expecting the magic?

Comment: what do you need the timer interrupt for?

Comment: The timer interrupt is only for debugging.